# SQL + inner select with different rowset

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a sql select with 3 inner selects:

```
select t1.a, t2.b, t3.c
from (select aa as a from ...) as t1 <-- query 1
     (select bb as b from ...) as t2 <-- query 2
     (select cc as c from ...) as t3 <-- query 3
where
t1.id = t2.id and t2.id = t3.id
```

The result set of query 1 has 5 rows.
The result set of query 2 has 5 rows.
The result set of query 3 has 2 rows.

So my sql displays only two rows because query 3 has 2 rows and I have a where codition: t1.id = t2.id and t2.id = t3.id.

But finally i would like to see 5 rows and where query 1 or/and 2 do not have any result I want to get  or default values.

If i remove the where conditions then I get many-many records as i expected but this is not also correct.

Could you tell me how can I solve it?

**Edit:**

This is the situation:

```
+--------+
| client |
+--------+
     |
+------------------+
| client_benchmark |
|                  |
| + fk_client_id   |
| + fk_kpi_id      |
| + value          |
| + last_update    |
+------------------+
    |
+------+
| kpi  |
+------+

insert into kpi (ID, NAME, ALIAS_NAME...) values (1, 'kpi 1'...);
insert into kpi (ID, NAME, ALIAS_NAME...) values (2, 'kpi 2'...);
insert into kpi (ID, NAME, ALIAS_NAME...) values (3, 'kpi 3'...);
insert into KPI (ID, NAME, ALIAS_NAME...) values (4, 'kpi 4'...);
...


insert into client_benchmark (ID, CLIENT_ID, KPI_ID, VALUE...) values (1, 1, 1, a1_1...);
insert into client_benchmark (ID, CLIENT_ID, KPI_ID, VALUE...) values (2, 1, 2, b1_2...);
...
insert into client_benchmark (ID, CLIENT_ID, KPI_ID, VALUE...) values (3, 2, 1, a2_1...);
insert into client_benchmark (ID, CLIENT_ID, KPI_ID, VALUE...) values (4, 2, 1, b2_2...);
insert into client_benchmark (ID, CLIENT_ID, KPI_ID, VALUE...) values (5, 2, 1, c2_3...);
insert into client_benchmark (ID, CLIENT_ID, KPI_ID, VALUE...) values (6, 2, 1, d2_4...);
insert into client_benchmark (ID, CLIENT_ID, KPI_ID, VALUE...) values (7, 2, 1, e2_5...);
...
insert into client_benchmark (ID, CLIENT_ID, KPI_ID, VALUE...) values (8, 3, 1, a3_1...);
insert into client_benchmark (ID, CLIENT_ID, KPI_ID, VALUE...) values (9, 3, 2, b3_2...);
...
```

i want to display this:

```
client_id | kpi_1.name | kpi_1.value | kpi_2.name | kpi_2.value | kpi_3.name | kpi_3.value
----------+------------+-------------+------------+-------------+------------+------------
1         | 'kpi 1'    | a1_1        | 'kpi 2'    | b1_2        | <null>     | <null>
2         | 'kpi 1'    | a2_1        | 'kpi 2'    | b2_2        | 'kpi 3'    | c2_3 
3         | 'kpi 1'    | a3_1        | 'kpi 2'    | b3_2        | <null>     | <null>
```

I need a fast and effective sql with as less as possible sql join command and I want to create a view table for this.

I use postgreSQL server.

Thx.

Comment: It sounds like you want LEFT OUTER or even FULL OUTER joins between these derived tables. Which RDBMS please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a [`LEFT JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join):

```
select
    t1.a
   ,t2.b
   ,t3.c
from table1      as t1
left join table2 as t2
  on t1.id = t2.id
left join table3 as t3
  on t2.id = t3.id
```

Unless you have complex logic in your sub-queries, it would probably be more readable if you just specify the table name in the `FROM`.

Answer (score 0):

JOIN?

```
select aa.a, bb.b, cc.c
from aa
  inner join bb on aa.id = bb.id
  inner join cc on cc.id = bb.id
where
  t1.id = t2.id and t2.id = t3.id
```